# looking for an element in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have the next js code that checks some name in my url, but I can't figure how to check more than one. I want to verify six names if they appear in the url, and I don't want to type this code for 6 times.

Is there a way to introduce more than one name in the if line?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urlSrtring = window.location.href;
    if (urlSrtring.indexOf('bogdan') !== -1) {
        alert('bb')
    }
} 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `array.prototype.every`:

```js
var urlSrtring = "xyzlqksjdlkabclkqsjdiztuv";

var strs = ['xyz', 'abc', 'tuv']

if (strs.every(str => urlSrtring.indexOf(str) !== -1)) {
  console.log('OK');
}
```

Comment: `includes` is another alternative to `indexOf` :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and a loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wordsToFind = ["word1", "word2","word3", "word4","word5", "word6"];
    var urlSrtring = window.location.href;
    for(var k=0; k< wordsToFind.length; k++){
    if (urlSrtring.indexOf(wordsToFind[k]) != -1) {
        alert('bb')
    }
}
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array with the names and execute either the `forEach` function or vanilla Javascript `for-loop`.

```js
var names = ["nippets", "net", "Jeff"];

var urlSrtring = window.location.href;
console.log(urlSrtring);
names.forEach(function(name) {
  if (urlSrtring.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
    console.log('bb');
  }
});
```